# cannot get my application server to be accessible from the internet

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Amazon recently killed a rails production server of mine because they stopped supporting ruby 2.3 on their elastic beanstalk platform.  I have been trying (desperately) to get new infrastructure setup using the CDK.

I was able to `aws execute-command` into my task and see that 1) it has database connectivity, and 2) I can curl to localhost:3000 and get responses, so everything in the container is working.

I am certain the problem has to do with my lack of understanding of security groups...

I have a database stack which creates a security group and opens up port 5432 to itself-- not sure if this is the right thing to do?

```
    const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'RdsSecurityGroup', {
      vpc,
      securityGroupName: SECURITY_GROUP_NAME,
    });
    securityGroup.addIngressRule(securityGroup, ec2.Port.tcp(5432));

    this.database = new rds.DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot(this, 'RdsDatabaseInstance', {
      credentials: rds.SnapshotCredentials.fromSecret(rdsCredentials),
      enablePerformanceInsights: true,
      engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres({ version: rds.PostgresEngineVersion.VER_12_14 }),
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
      multiAz: true,
      publiclyAccessible: false,
      snapshotIdentifier: DATABASE_SNAPSHOT,
      securityGroups: [securityGroup],
      vpc,
      vpcSubnets: {
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then my cluster stack looks up that security group and adds it to the service that creates the load balanced cluster:

```
    const rdsSsecurityGroup = ec2.SecurityGroup.fromLookupByName(this, 'RdsSecurityGroup', SECURITY_GROUP_NAME, vpc);

    const app = taskDefinition.addContainer('TaskDefinition', {
      environment: {
        'RDS_HOSTNAME': database.dbInstanceEndpointAddress,
        'RDS_PORT': database.dbInstanceEndpointPort,
        'RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES': 'true',
      },
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(dockerImageAsset),
      logging: ecs.LogDriver.awsLogs({ streamPrefix: 'noteblaster-server' }),
    });

    app.addPortMappings({
      containerPort: 3000,
      protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP,
    });

    const service = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'FargateService', {
      cluster: cluster,
      cpu: 1,
      desiredCount: 1,
      domainName: DOMAIN_NAME,
      domainZone: hostedZone,
      enableExecuteCommand: true,
      memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
      protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
      publicLoadBalancer: true,
      redirectHTTP: true,
      securityGroups: [
        rdsSsecurityGroup,
      ],
      taskDefinition: taskDefinition,
    });
  }
```

My load balancer shows it has inbound rules for 80 and 443, and one outbound rule going to 3000, but it showed the destination being my rds security group-- which seems totally wrong.

Comment: The ingress rule on port 5432 from itself seems to be a shortcut by whoever set this up because both the RDS instance and the ALB for your ECS/Fargate deployment have that security group and it will allow traffic from your Fargate service to the RDS instance. Not an ideal setup but shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @gshpychka, so the title of this post is "cannot get my application server to be accessible from the internet" and the 2nd paragraph I wrote says "it has database connectivity"

Comment: @jarmod I set this up.  can you please give me guidance on how I should be setting up these security groups?

Comment: Typically your compute nodes (ECS, EC2, Lambda etc.) would have SG A and RDS would have SG B with an ingress rule allowing TCP/5432 from SG A. Both SGs would have default egress rules (0.0.0.0/0, All, All). That said, what you have should also work.

Comment: PS the ALB outbound rule going to port 3000 of the RDS security group, which seems wrong to you, is a by-product of having used the same SG for both the compute instances and the RDS instance. This is actually client HTTP(s) traffic from the ALB being routed to the containerized app on port 3000.

Comment: What do your ALB [health checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html) show?

Comment: @jarmod, I am not sure what to look for to answer that.. When I go to the service in ecs, I see "1 Unhealthy", when I go to the task I see "Task failed ELB health checks in target-group" .. If I go to the load balancer dns and the health check path, I see 502 or 503, depending on whether the task is running or not (it's constantly going between running / draining / stopped).

Comment: Afaik, 503 means there are zero healthy targets, and 502 means your back-end app returned an error response. Suggest you debug what's going on with the application.

Comment: @jarmod as I said in my 2nd paragraph, "I was able to aws execute-command into my task and see that 1) it has database connectivity, and 2) I can curl to localhost:3000 and get responses, so everything in the container is working" ... The app is working fine, it is just that it cannot be connected to.

Comment: Does the SG allow inbound port 3000 (for traffic from ALB) as well as 5432?

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 security groups and use security group chaining technique, example:

```
    // ################## ALB-SG ######################
    const albSG = new SecurityGroup(this, 'AlbSg', {
      vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true,  // just an example
    })
    albSG.addIngressRule(Peer.anyIpv4(), Port.tcp(443))
    albSG.addIngressRule(Peer.anyIpv4(), Port.tcp(80))

    // ################## APP-SG ######################
    const appSG = new SecurityGroup(this, 'AppSg', {
      vpc,
    })
    appSG.addIngressRule(Peer.securityGroupId(albSG.securityGroupId), Port.tcp(3000))

    // ################## DB-SG ######################
    const dbGg = new SecurityGroup(this, 'DbSg', {
      vpc,
    })
    dbGg.addIngressRule(Peer.securityGroupId(appSG.securityGroupId), Port.tcp(5432))
    appSG.addEgressRule(Peer.securityGroupId(dbGg.securityGroupId), Port.tcp(5432))
```

I hope it's enough to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not security groups..  It was rails server binding to `localhost` which is inaccessible.  I needed to `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` and then everything worked.